# Why list index out of range (sieve of eratosthenes)?

Tags: python

```
import math

maks=18
tab = []
for i in range(2, maks + 1):
   tab.append(i)

end = int(math.sqrt(maks))
for j in range(2, end + 1):
   for c in range(len(tab)):
      if tab[c]%j ==0 and tab[c] != j:
         del tab[c]
```

Error:

> if tab[c]%j ==0 and tab[c] != j:
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Deleting from the list you're iterating over is usually a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Because you change the length of the list while you're iterating over it: `del tab[c]`. This also breaks the sieve; you should set the value to e.g. `None` then filter it afterwards.